# Can't access EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am learning AWS and Terraform, following an Udemy course on the topic.

I set up an instance, added the necessary rules for networks, but I can't access the instance through public ip using browser (8080) or SSH-ing into it (22).

For SSH, the error is:

```
ssh: connect to host *ip here* port 22: Connection timed out
```

For HTTP:

```
Unable to connect
Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at *ip*:8080
```

#### main.tf

```
provider "aws" {
    region = "eu-west-3"
}

variable vpc_cidr_block {}
variable subnet_cidr_block {}
variable avail_zone {}
variable env_prefix {}
variable my_ip {}
variable instance_type {}
variable public_key_location {}

resource "aws_vpc" "myapp-vpc" {
  cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr_block
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env_prefix}-vpc"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "myapp-subnet-1" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myapp-vpc.id
  cidr_block = var.subnet_cidr_block
  availability_zone = var.avail_zone
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env_prefix}-subnet-1"
  }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "myapp-igw" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myapp-vpc.id
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env_prefix}-igw"
  }
}

resource "aws_default_route_table" "main-rtb" {
  default_route_table_id = aws_vpc.myapp-vpc.default_route_table_id

  route {
    cidr_block = "0.0.0.0/0"
    gateway_id = aws_internet_gateway.myapp-igw.id
  }
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env_prefix}-main-rtb"
  }
}

resource "aws_default_security_group" "default-sg" {
  vpc_id = aws_vpc.myapp-vpc.id

  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [var.my_ip]
  }

  ingress {
    from_port   = 8080
    to_port     = 8080
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }

  egress {
    from_port       = 0
    to_port         = 0
    protocol        = "-1"
    cidr_blocks     = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    prefix_list_ids = []
  }

  tags = {
    Name = "${var.env_prefix}-default-sg"
  }
}

data "aws_ami" "latest-amazon-linux-image" {
  most_recent = true
  owners = ["amazon"]
  filter {
    name = "name"
    values = ["amzn2-ami-hvm-*-x86_64-gp2"]
  }
  filter {
    name = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }
}

output "aws_ami_id" {
  value = data.aws_ami.latest-amazon-linux-image.id
}

output "ec2_public_ip" {
  value = aws_instance.myapp-server.public_ip
}

resource "aws_key_pair" "ssh-key" {
  key_name = "server-key"
  public_key = file(var.public_key_location)
}

resource "aws_instance" "myapp-server" {
  ami                         = data.aws_ami.latest-amazon-linux-image.id
  instance_type               = var.instance_type
  subnet_id                   = aws_subnet.myapp-subnet-1.id
  vpc_security_group_ids      = [aws_default_security_group.default-sg.id]
  availability_zone           = var.avail_zone
  associate_public_ip_address = true
  key_name = aws_key_pair.ssh-key.key_name

  user_data = file("entry-script.sh")

  tags = {
        Name = "${var.env_prefix}-server"
  }
}
```

#### entry-script.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y && sudo yum install -y docker
sudo systemctl start docker
sudo usermod -aG docker ec2-user
docker run -p 8080:80 nginx
```

#### Security Group's inbound rules

```
Name Security group rule ID IP version Type Protocol Port range Source Description
–   sgr-0bcbda1a7b9d6e6a8   IPv4    SSH TCP 22  *myIpHere*/32   –
–   sgr-02ebfb5a794a8bd17   IPv4    Custom TCP  TCP 8080    0.0.0.0/0   –
```

#### Subnet's Route Table

```
Destination Target
10.0.0.0/16 local
0.0.0.0/0   igw-0c111019740d3621b
```

#### Network ACL Inbound

```
Rule number Type Protocol Port range Source Allow/Deny
100         HTTP* (8080)    TCP (6) 8080    0.0.0.0/0   Allow
*       All traffic All     All             0.0.0.0/0   Deny
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Re-check main.tf, set-up on AWS, docs
2. Re-generate SSH keys
3. Check local firewall settings
4. Destroy and apply everything (5+ times)
5. Try from other computer

My suspicion is on this ACL Inbound rule with number *, but the AWS UI does not allow me to edit it or remove it (I don't know why).

I've been stuck on this for 2 days now, so any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: The NACL seems to be the issue. You can just add a rule for SSH instead of trying to remove the implicit deny rule which I don't think is even possible. Bear in mind that NACLs are stateless, meaning that if you define a port inbound, you have to define it in outbound direction as well.

Comment: @MarkoE I added NACL rule for SSH (both inbound and outbound), and still can't ssh into it (Connection timed out). I added the rules first for my IP, but then changed it to any IP, and still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't state what is the error when you try to ssh.

- If it is **connection timeout**, it has to be a network issue.
- If it is **permission denied**, it is ssh-related issue. You might be connecting with the wrong key or the wrong user: for example, ubuntu if ubuntu OS, ec2-user if amzn ami.

In general, if you are a newbie in AWS, do things first your hand, then automate it. **Automating what you don't know is never a good idea**. Also try to create in the default VPC instead of a new one first; for example, **enable_dns_hostnames** is not enabled by default on new VPCs.

Comment: I just updated the post with the error messages. The problem is "connection timeout". The instructor of the course started the course with building VPC, I just followed. I'll try to switch to default one now.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to the NACL's, they are stateless and you need to add the ephemeral port range (1024 – 65535, so not just port 22!) for the other side of the rule. See here some more information:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-network-acls.html#nacl-ephemeral-ports

Also it could help if you post the VPC flow logs for this ENI after connecting through SSH. This can help debug the problem to see if the problem is on the outbound or the inbound connection.

Security groups are stateful so they automatically allow the other side of the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may be disturbed default vpc settings.
First check your public IP has internet connection by ping your public IP.

If no response check route table and fix it!

Answer (score 0):

There is a default `"Deny"` rule for all other traffic, which could be blocking SSH access on `port 22`

By adding Rule number 200 for SSH traffic, you explicitly allow inbound SSH connections on `port 22` from any source `(0.0.0.0/0)`. Make sure to update the network ACL configuration accordingly.

After making the necessary changes, try accessing the instance through the public IP using a browser on `port 8080` and SSH on `port 22` again.